# Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2018/10. Is its parent directory writable by the server

Tags: wordpress, docker

I have a docker wordpress image running and i am getting this error. I have tried various solutions such as chmod 777 and chmod for the wp-content directory also but to no avail.

```
FROM wordpress:php7.2-apache

COPY content/ /var/www/html/wp-content
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads


EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Which Wordpress image are you using? If you're using your own, post the Dockerfile please.

Comment: I have added my dockerfile.